# Split string on two delimiters?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to split a string based on the delimiters `" "` and `","` (including quotation marks). How would I be able to do this? I tried doing this:

```js
var str = '"String","String2" "String3"';
str = str.split('" "', '","');
console.log(str);
```

But it didn't work. I was expecting this console output:

```
["String", "String2", "String3"]
```

But I got:

```
[]
```

How do I split a string based on two delimiters? Is it possible?

Comment: What is result you are expecting? Kindly share that.

Comment: Oh sorry @PrasannaBrabourame, I'll edit my question

Comment: @PrasannaBrabourame better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let str = '"String","String2" "String3"';
str = str.split(/ |,/);
console.log(str);

let str2 = '"String","String2" "String3"';
str2 = str2.split(/" "|","|"|\n/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(str2);

let str3 = '"String","String2" "String3"';
str3 = str3.match(/[\w\d]+/g);
console.log(str3);
```

Comment: that second one is exactly what I want, thanks so much!

Comment: how would I also check for a newline character? Could you please edit your answer?

Comment: I haven't test it. Do you have a string example to split?

Comment: No need - it works perfectly! Thanks so much @Piterden!

Comment: @shiv-kumar-baghel look at the third variant

Comment: NP, I had used that regex split on one of my opensource project https://github.com/Piterden/vue-crossword/blob/master/src/components/BuilderPage.vue#L79

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex: `str = str.split(/,| /)`

```js
console.log("a,b c".split(/,| /));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify regex or array as delimiter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

try below solution

```js
var str = '"String","String2" "String3"';

str = str.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g)

str = str.map(function(x){return x.replace(/"/g, '');});

console.log('Final str : ', str);
```

Comment: `str3.match(/[\w\d]+/g)`